# JSON and Jquery tree in JSP

Tags: java, json, jstl

Firstly, I am sending some parameters and with the response JSON String I am doing some conversions and adding it into list and then from spring controller passing it to JSP.

So, In my JSP I am using a for loop to render the data like,

```
<c:forEach var="treeList" items="${JSONResult.jsonList}" varStatus='treeStatus'>
    { "title": "<c:out value='${treeList.name}' />", "key": "<c:out value='${treeList.id}' />" }
    <c:if test="${!(treeStatus.last)}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

with this I am getting JSON Error as,

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

But if I put the simple data like,

```
{ "title": "Node 1", "key": "1" }
```

Then It is working fine.

Also, I kept alert on error as XMLResponse.toSource() and I see like,
\r and \n appended a lot.

Please help me out why it is not accepting the response.

Comment: It would help if you posted the JSON that _doesn't_ work :)

Comment: Are you sure, all java values are not empty? Will the same error occur if you add the parameter 'xmlEscape="false"' to the output tag?

Comment: yes I am sure, No empty output tags

Comment: @Richard: If I understood write, u need the code from ajax error i alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided code will output the following,

```
{ "title": "Node 1", "key": "1" },
{ "title": "Node 2", "key": "2" },
{ "title": "Node 3, "key": "3" }
```

You need to surround that with another set of brackets

```
{"data": [
<c:forEach var="treeList" items="${JSONResult.jsonList}" varStatus='treeStatus'>
    { "title": "<c:out value='${treeList.name}' />", "key": "<c:out value='${treeList.id}' />" }
    <c:if test="${!(treeStatus.last)}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
]}
```

A well formed object starts with a bracket and ends with a bracket, you are sending multiple objects delimited by commas whihich is not correct.

[image: Proper json object]

So a coorect version will look like,

```
{ "data": [{ "title": "Node 1", "key": "1" },
 { "title": "Node 2", "key": "2" },
 { "title": "Node 3, "key": "3" }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just found the answer,

```
[
<c:forEach var="treeList" items="${JSONResult.jsonList}" varStatus='treeStatus'>
    { "title": "<c:out value='${treeList.name}' />", "key": "<c:out value='${treeList.id}' />" }
    <c:if test="${!(treeStatus.last)}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
]
```

works. Missing are the '[' and ']'. Thanks for your support.